# Running a login shell using sudo inside a shell script on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, shell, sudo, su

I am trying to run some bash scripts that we wrote on Linux on Mac OS X Mountain Lion. The script performs a

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su -l <username>  << EOF
echo $HOME
#execute command that is only on the path of <username>
EOF
```

No I am running the script as **user1** and I am in the script trying to switch to **user2**. I actually need it to run like this as there are other portions that need to run as user1.

On linux I get

```
/home/user2
```

On Mac OS X I get

```
/Users/user1
```

So its not actually performing a login and as such any script that relies on us being logged in as user2 then fails as it doesn't reference either .bash_profile/.bashrc for user2

Been struggling with this for a while now and it seems as if there is now way to get OS X to behave in the same way as linux does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell is interpreting the `$HOME` variable in the heredoc, before the input reaches the `su` shell. You need to escape the `$`:

```
bash-3.2$ sudo su -l root <<EOF
> echo $HOME
> echo \$HOME
> EOF
/Users/kevin
/var/root
```

The real question is why does it work on your Linux box.

Comment: Thanks, that helps alot, re the linux box seems like someones messed around with that user. But the real issue I have is Mac OS X not running the .bashrc.

Now that I have a handle on the $HOME its no longer an issue I hope.